# Differently colored points inside the circle

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

Let

```
Ar1 = {{1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2}}, Ar2 = {{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, -1/2}}
```

and

```
Plot[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {{PointSize[Large], Point[Ar1]}, {PointSize[Large], 
    Point[Ar2]}}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0]]
```

Can you make the points given by `Ar1` and `Ar2` look different (differently colored/styled) inside the circle?

Comment: Please take a look at `RandomColor[]`.

Comment: For example, if you change `PointSize[Large]` to `PointSize[Medium]` then `Ar1` will be smaller than `Ar2`. Or if you insert a color (`{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Ar1]}`) then it will have a different color. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: `Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Ar1], Green, Point[Ar2]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Ar1 = {{1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2}}; Ar2 = {{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, -1/2}};

Show[
 Plot[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, {x, -1, 1},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0]],
 ListPlot[{Ar1, Ar2},
  PlotMarkers -> {"OpenMarkers", 10},
  PlotLegends -> {"Ar1", "Ar2"}]]
```

[image]